# How to automatically add file location while printing

Tags: printing

I'd like to print a lot of text documents and I'd like to have a file location on the footer of each page of all documents. Of course I don't want to add them manually, but I'd like to set have them there automatically added just for printing. Is there a way how to achieve this in TextEdit or Pages?

Answer (score 1):

As automagic as it gets:

Using the add on service from http://www.devontechnologies.com/download/products.html

Example -total of 37 choices)

WordService provides a large number of commands for working with selected text:

```
Reformat text paragraphs
Clean up tabs, quotes, line endings
Remove unwanted text parts
Sort lines or paragraphs
Change case
Shift paragraphs right or left
Obscure using Rotate 13
Insert date, time, or file path
Get text statistics
```

Download from App Store for free.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordservice/id899972312?mt=12

you select Insert File path and voila.